# Stop Debugging by pressing esc key

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have one form. I want to close the form by pressing escape key i also want debugging to be stop.I am closing by clicking button here is the code

```
Private Sub Form2_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

    Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            Application.Exit()                                                                               ' Close the form and also debugging
            'nothing to do here the form is already closing
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            e.Cancel = True 'cancel the form closing event
            'minimize to tray/hide etc here 
    End Select




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple solution:

```
Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
     Select Case e.Key
               Case Key.Escape
                    Me.close()
               Case Else
                    ' do nothing
     End Select
End Sub
```

Hope this help.